# ionic 4 ion-back-button is always return to "root" page

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

In my application I use ion-back-view and I notice that the back button is always return to "root" page (first page that loaded), so after investigation in code, I saw that the router.navigate always set view as first view.

these is code from stack-controller.ts

```
 StackController.prototype.insertView = function (enteringView, direction) {
        // no stack
        if (!this.stack) {
            this.views = [enteringView];
            return;
        }
        // stack setRoot
        if (direction === 0) {
            this.views = [enteringView];
            return;
        }
        // stack
        var index = this.views.indexOf(enteringView);
        if (index >= 0) {
            this.views = this.views.slice(0, index + 1);
        }
        else {
            if (direction === 1) {
                this.views.push(enteringView);
            }
            else {
                this.views = [enteringView];
            }
        }
    };
```

here each view set as first view and not added to stack,

```
 if (direction === 0) {
            this.views = [enteringView];
            return;
        }
```

then how can I add views to stack from code not html (routerDirection) ? 
https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-v4-routing-and-root/135439/3

Comment: You are creating custom navigation views array?

Comment: I'm trying to use NavController

instead of using

this.router.navigate(['test]);

I'm trying to use

this.navCtrl.navigateForward(['test']);

but I think  that (navCtrl) is deprecated and I face other issue, when forward and return back and need to forward again it's not working.

@PareshGami

Comment: @PareshGami no, I don't create custom navigation views array.

Comment: Yes.! navCtrl deprecated in ionic 4. Need to play with the router only.!

Comment: @PareshGami but as I notices the navController build on router

NavController.prototype.navigateForward = function (url, animated, extras) {
        this.setIntent(1 /* Forward */, animated);
        if (Array.isArray(url)) {
            return this.router.navigate(url, extras);
        }
        else {
            return this.router.navigateByUrl(url, extras);
        }
    };

Answer (score 1):

After migrated one of our PWA from Ionic 3 to Ionic 4, I found out that the routing is changed completely and you really need to think in Angular way instead of Ionic 3.

Each navigation (forward and back) will trigger the router lifecycle, which means if you have any guard, redirect rules, it WILL be called.

EXAMPLE:

Let's say you have 3 tabs 'home', 'notification' and 'more'. You need user see `home` tab when loaded the app. `notification` tab contains many notifications and you can nav into detail by clicking it. Meanwhile, you also want to navigate into one of the notification detail from `home` tab.

Routes in `app.routing.ts`

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'tabs', loadChildren: './pages/tabs/tabs.module#TabsModule' },
  {
    path: 'notification/:id',
    loadChildren: './pages/notification/notification-detail/notification-detail.module#NotificationDetailPageModule'
  },
  { path: 'login', loadChildren: './pages/login/login.module#LoginPageModule' },
  { path: '**', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'tabs/home' }
];
```

TIPS:

- If you want to stay in each tab you left before, do not add empty redirect rule in `tabs.routing.ts`.
- If you want to hide tab-bar in a subpage, do not add the page under `tabs` routes.

Routes in `tabs.routing.ts`

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: TabsPage,
    children: [
      { path: 'home', children: [{ path: '', component: HomePage }]},
      { path: 'notification', children: [{ path: '', loadChildren: '../notification/notification-list/notification-list.module#NotificationListPageModule' }]},
      { path: 'more', children: [{ path: '', loadChildren: '../more/more-index/more-index.module#MoreIndexPageModule' }]}
    ]
  }];
```

Comment: This custom component appears to have a O(N) of N^3. That doesn't seem to be too performant, calling a triple nested loop each time you hit back. How well would this scale?

Comment: In practice, this performs well. Because in most cases you don't have more than 5 tabs in your app.

Answer (score 1):

For a temporary workaround you could use the NavController and do a (click)="navCtrl.back()" in the ion-back-button element.

Comment: When you navigating back like this, you will lose the state inside your tabs. This is because internally it navigates back to with the _wrong ion-back-button logic_ (e.g. to `/tabs`) and then to the route specified in your `(click)` function. See my [solutions](https://github.com/servrox/demo-ionic-tabs-back-button#solutions-shown-in-demo) to navigate back without losing tab-states.

Answer (score 0):

There's an open [bug](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/15216) which describes problems with the `ion-back button`.
I think this is because the `ion-back-button` uses only the *main-IonRouterOutlet*, instead of also checking *tabs-IonRouterOutlet*.
Which means that the *StackController* inside the *main-IonRouterOutlet* only knows the route of the tabs module (e.g. 'tabs').

See my Ionic 4 [demo project](https://github.com/servrox/demo-ionic-tabs-back-button) with a fix and workarounds for the `ion-back-button`.

The demo shows [two ways](https://github.com/servrox/demo-ionic-tabs-back-button#solutions-shown-in-demo) how to navigate from a *'tabbed page'* to a *'global page'* and back, **without losing tab-states**.

My custom [ion-back-button-tabs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ion-back-button-tabs) component accessing the problem explained above directly (also shown in [demo](https://github.com/servrox/demo-ionic-tabs-back-button#2-using-ion-back-button-tabs-component-s-global-page-two)). `ion-back-button-tabs` uses the `ion-back-button` internally, however, it's additionally checked whether to navigate to a *'tabbed page'* and if so, the last active tab route is determined.